# CtrlPBuffer path before filename

Tags: plugin-ctrlp

I like using the CtrlP plugin's `CtrlPBuffer` command for quickly switching between buffers, as well as using `CtrlP` for navigating to files not yet opened. However, I have one annoyance I'd like to fix. When I use `CtrlPBuffer`, it shows a list of files with the filename in the first column and the containing path in the second column. This means when I want to match a file, I need to enter the filename first and then the path. However, for the regular `CtrlP` command, this is reversed. I'd like to have this consistent, i.e. that for `CtrlPBuffer` I can enter parts of the path before entering parts of the filename.

For example, if my directory tree contains:

```
folder/file.py
folder2/file.py
```

Entering `2f` will match the second file when using `CtrlP`, but not when using `CtrlPBuffer`. Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `ctrlp_bufname_mod` on your .vimrc file:

`let g:ctrlp_bufname_mod = ':p'`

You can finetune this, check `filename-modifiers` in CtrlP docs (`:help filename-modifiers`)

Comment: Nice, thanks! I've settled on `let g:ctrlp_bufname_mod = ':~:.'`, which does exactly what I want.